# Why isn't ReSharper and/or Microsoft Code Analysis complaining about this nonlocalized string?

Tags: c#, localization, resharper, code-analysis, nlog

I've added a log message to my C# code:

```
Log.Info("Why no complaint about this nonlocalized string?");
```

As it indicates, I get no complaint from ReSharper or Microsoft Code Analysis about the fact that I'm using a nonlocalized string.  I think I have things set up to complain about localization issues:

For ReSharper, I have the project's "Localizable" set to "Yes", and "Localizable Inspector" set to "Pessimistic".

For Microsoft Code Analysis, I have the project's rule set set to "Microsoft All Rules".

I've definitely gotten complaints from at least one of them, and I think both of them, in the past about things like this, with (I think) these same settings.  Am I missing something?

The little description of the project's "Localizable" setting in the Properties pane says "By default, ReSharper only highlights localizable items if one or more resource files are available in the project."  I have "Localizable" set to "Yes", not "Default", so it seems like this shouldn't apply to me (and I am pretty certain it didn't apply to me in similar situations in the past), but it's a brand new project that didn't yet have a resource file, so I decided to add one in just to see if it would help.  It did not - the issue remains.

I am using VS2012 and ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2.  I have used this exact combination of products/versions in the past with success along these lines.

**UPDATE:** It seems like it has something to do with Log.Info? ReSharper will complain about either of the following lines:

```
var blah = "Why no complaint about this nonlocalized string?";

System.Console.WriteLine("Why no complaint about this nonlocalized string?");
```

But it will *not* complain about this one:

```
Log.Info("Why no complaint about this nonlocalized string?");
```

Interestingly, it *will* complain about this one:

```
Log.Info("Why no complaint about this nonlocalized string? {0}", blah);
```

"Log" is a NLog.Logger, defined in the class as follows:

```
private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Log.Info` has an `[Localizable(false)]` attribute: 
 [`public void Info([Localizable(false)] string message)`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/6483571d02a098320dbb33a484340397abc5b37a/src/NLog/Logger1.cs#L721)

Comment: Thanks.  Why? Is there a way around this?

Comment: No way around I guess. But why should log (files) be localized?

Comment: I guess I tend to think of logging frameworks as being potentially useful for more than strictly just files for the review of internal support people or programmers or whatever; logging frameworks can be useful for end user-facing features, too.  Or more generally for customer-facing features, where "customer" might or might not be "end user".  So it seemed kind of surprising to me that it's not my choice whether log messages are localizable or not.

I have found a workaround, though: Use the delegate-based version of the call.  This apparently doesn't have [Localizable(false)].

Comment: I think 99% of the logs aren't meant for localizing. But if there is a trick we can make this optional at NLog, just let me know